# jQuery Rotater fails when I hide and show new content

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I'm trying to make a slider by jQuery, I'm creating a yearly slider to show the best news in a given year.

I can make my slider go from left to right automatically and by the click of a button. However when I hide my 2003 content and try to append my 2004 content the slider fails to function, it won't slide automatically or via a click.

In fact when I add the 2004 content into the page the slider starts to extend, I suppose that's because I have included the slider in with the same classes and ID etc, so its confusing my slider.

Does anyone know of a solution or perhaps how I could go about this in a different way?

I've created a simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal90/UUHhV/) or view my code below:

index.html

```
<div id="newsrotatorwrapper">
  <div id="newsrotator" class="year2003">
  <div class="newsyear">
   <h2 class="timeline_year">2003</h2>
   </div>

     <div id="slider">
         <div class="newscontent">
                <h3 class="timeline_heading">Concorde comes to an end</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">British Airways and Air France made simultaneous announcements that they would be permanently grounding the famous supersonic airliners in 2003. Passenger numbers had never recovered since the crash near Paris in 2000 and the aircraft was unprofitable.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="newscontent">
                        <h3 class="timeline_heading">Apple Launches Safari Browser</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">“Safari is the fastest browser on the Mac, and we predict that many will feel it is the best browser ever created,” said Steve Jobs, Apple’s CEO. “We are bringing innovation back into this category with the first all new browser created in many years.”</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="newscontent">
                        <h3 class="timeline_heading">LOTR: Return of the King</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Seven years ago when Jackson began working on the trilogy, "The Lord of the Rings" wasn't being looked at as the hottest property, at least beyond the fantasy fans who long obsessed over the idea of a proper live-action treatment of J.R.R. Tolkein's books. But now, after the mind-blowing achievements of "The Two Towers" and the "The Fellowship of the Ring," it would seem that the fans have taken over.</p>
                        </div>                
                    </div> <!-- end slider -->
                </div> <!-- End news rotator -->


      <div id="newsrotator" class="year2004">
                    <div class="newsyear">
                    <h2 class="timeline_year">2004</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div id="slider">
                        <div class="newscontent">
                        <h3 class="timeline_heading">Loreum Ipsum</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="newscontent">
                        <h3 class="timeline_heading">Loreum Ipsum 2</h3>
                        <p class="timeline_content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                        </div>

                    </div> <!-- end slider -->
                </div> <!-- End news rotator -->



                <div id="rotator_arrows_wrapper">
                    <span  class="rotatorarrows" id="left">Prev</span>
                    <span class="rotatorarrows" id="right">Next</span>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- End news roator wrapper --> 
 <button id="2004btn">2004</button>
```

js/js.js

// new rotate

```
var W = $('#newsrotator').width();      // gallery width
var N = $('#slider .newscontent').length;    // number of elements
var C = 0;                          // counter
var intv;                         // auto anim. interval


if(N<=1){ 
  $('#left, #right').hide();  // hide buttons only 1 element
}  


$('#slider').width( W*N );          // set slsider width

$('#left, #right').click(function(){

  if(this.id=='right'){

    C++;
    C = C % N;     // reset to '0' if end reached

  }else{ // left was clicked

    C--;
    if(C===-1){   // IF C turns -1 scroll to last one (N-1)
      C = N-1; 
    }

  }

  $('#slider').stop().animate({left: -C*W }, 1000 );
});


// auto rotate

function autoRotate(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
      $('#right').click();
  },8000); // pause time
}
autoRotate(); // start auto rotate

// pause hover

$('#newsrotator').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){
   var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter';
  if(mEnt){
     clearInterval(intv);
  }else{
     autoRotate();
  }
});

$('#2004btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.year2003').fadeOut();
    $('.year2004').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicate ID values: #newsrotator

This is invalid HTML and jQuery will only act on the first. You need to change your thinking about IDs and classes--the former should be for uniqueness and the latter for multiple-use scenarios (a "class" of elements).

If you take a look at how most popular sliders work, you pass an ID into the function, and all event handlers inside that are relative to $(this), which is the passed ID. You'll need to restructure in that manner and call your ID when you use the button to switch sliders.

Update: Here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/UUHhV/6/

```
// build the rotator
var myRotator = function (myId) {
    ... all the rotator goodies ...
}

// call the rotator on the first element
myRotator('#newsrotator1');

// switch elements and call the rotator on the second element
$('#2004btn').on('click', function () {
    $('.year2003').fadeOut();
    myRotator('#newsrotator2');
    $('.year2004').fadeIn();
});
```